# Intro to stats probability inequality question

Tags: statistics

y    :  10      20     25       30      45    50
p(y) :0.155   0.237   0.184   0.122     ?    0.258

a. Find p(45).

b. Find P(Y ≥ 25) and P(Y > 25).

c. Find the probability Y is divisible by 10.

Comment: the p(y) is in direct correlation with the numbers above

Comment: Is $Y$ a random variable and $P(Y)$ the values of its probability function?

Comment: yes i believe it is

Comment: yes i believe it is

Answer (score 2):

The possible values of your random variable are:
$$y = (10, 20, 25, 30, 45, 50)$$ and the respective
probabilities in the PDF are
$$p = (0.155, 0.237, 0.184, 0.122, 0.044, 0.258),$$
where the `?` is replaced by `0.044` in order for the
probabilities to add to $1,$ as they must.

Then $p(45) = 0.044.$ Also, 
$$P(Y \ge 25) = 0.184 + 0.122 + 0.044 + 0.258.$$
And so on.

Note: Maybe the next step in your study of random variables is to find the mean of this one:
$$\mu = 10(0.155) + 20(0.237) + \dots + 50(0.258) = 29.43.$$

Below is a bar graph of your 'probability distribution function'
(or 'point mass function'). Does it look to you as if this graph 'balances' at
$\mu = 29.43$?

[image]

Comment: Thank you that was helpful, but I just don't get part C

Comment: I believe @Sean Roberson has just helped you with that. Add the probabilities for 10, 20, 30 and 50.

Answer (score 1):

I shall only provide hints.

A. If $f(y)$ is a probability mass function for a discrete random variable, then

$$ \sum_{y \in Y} f(y) = 1 $$

i.e., all the probabilities sum to $1$. Add the given values and subtract from $1$.

B. The expression $P(Y \geq y)$ means that you are finding the probability that $Y$ is larger than $y$. Add the probabilities for any $y$ that satisfy this condition. The second part is similar but the inequality is strict.

C. Similar to B, except the condition is divisibility. Which $y$ satisfy the condition? Add.

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't understand part C.

Comment: Do you understand what it means to say one number is divisible by another (say, 21 is divisible by 3)? We need that for C, and the computation is similar to B in that you add those probabilities $p(y)$ for which $y$ is divisible by 10.

Comment: If you have what you need on this, I suggest you click to Accept @SeanRoberson's answer (which was first, excellent, and right to the point) so this can go off our list of questions yet to be answered.